# Using LocalDB on several SQL Servers on one PC

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have several SQL Servers on my system - SQL Server 2008 Express, SQL Server 2017:

[image]

```
select  @@version
```

returns:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1) - 10.0.2531.0 (X64)   
Mar 29 2009 10:11:52   
Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  
Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: ) 

Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64)   
Aug 22 2017 17:04:49   
Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  
Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0 <X64> (Build 15063: )
```

But why does the `sqllocaldb` utility show that I have `v11.0`? I suppose this is SQL Server 2012. I was expecting v10.0 there:

```
sqllocaldb info 
MSSQLLocalDB
v11.0
```

It is also interesting that I should use `Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0` in connection string in order to connect to `localDB`.

Wow to describe such version mixture?

How to bring possibility to connect via localDB to my computer? Should I install addition driver for that?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio do you have installed? I'd suspect that you are seeing the VS instance of localDB.

Comment: There's a difference between versions available and actual instances created. `sqllocaldb create <instance> <version>`. You can have any number of instances with any version available. Without having a full edition of SQL Server installed, LocalDB is also available as an individual download (for each separate version). It is possible to share LocalDB instances across users (`sqllocaldb share`), but not across machines -- LocalDB does not have the TCP/IP transport enabled. Use SQL Server Express if you want an instance that can be reached remotely.

Comment: I have almost all VS - 2010,2012,2013,2014,2015,2017. What does it means "VS instance of localDB"? Does it means that each visual studio brings SQL server?

Comment: I'm happy with localDB since I need to commit database to SVN and other developer will not need to create DB on its machine. I need db on the same machine where code runs

Comment: `LocalDB is also available as an individual download (for each separate version)` Where I can download LocalDB ?